# add_index to Data Model - Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, indexing

I am just a bit stuck on this code found in the Ruby on Rails Tutorial.org. What exactly does the **add_index** part of it do? Why are there 3 lines for this?

```
    class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followed_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :relationships, :follower_id
    add_index :relationships, :followed_id
    add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> A database index is a data structure that improves the speed of
>   operations in a table. Indexes can be created using one or more
>   columns, providing the basis for both rapid random lookups and
>   efficient ordering of access to records. - [TutorialPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm)

Basically Index used to speed up the query.

In the example

```
add_index :relationships, :follower_id
add_index :relationships, :followed_id
```

index is created for `follower_id` and `followed_id` column which will speed up the query looking for `follower_id` **OR** `followed_id`. It does not enforce any other constraints on your column like **UNIQUE**. So they can have identical values

Here

```
add_index :relationships, [:follower_id, :followed_id], unique: true
```

the process is same as above with a constraint that `follower_id` **AND** `followed_id` combinations should be distinct. An Error will be thrown if you try to duplicate identical combined values for these columns in multiple rows.

Comment: thanks for your comment, so could I compare an index to like a contents of a book or an 'index' of a book where it is faster to find areas that can narrow down to information (tables in db)? Also would the above indexing be practical and necessary to query the database? Why, why not?

Comment: Yes it would be faster to narrow down the information but the only drawback is indexing will take time whenever you add/edit rows.

Comment: okay thanks for that but since their are only 2 columns (follower_id and followed_id) why would their be a need for an index? (sorry, I'm just trying to get my head around it). Does the index sort them is some way? It just seems a bit strange to me to add an index to a table with 2 columns, what does the index do to the rows? Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: No. of columns or rows doesn't matter creating index is a choice its totally upto you. check this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/02/indexes-in-mysql/

Comment: An index is like a hash.  So the indexes above will tell the database to keep a hash with the follower_id as a key to each record (as the value of the hash), keep a hash with the followed_id as a key to each record, and to keep a hash with key follower_id, where its value is a hash with key followed_id and that has the value of the record in the database.

Comment: @MarlinPierce what would the hash translate to though? 'cos suppose it  translates to a record number. If a record is deleted then if record numbers change then it'd point to the wrong record.. So what is it translating to exactly (that lets it access a record straight away even if records around it are deleted)?

Comment: @barlop I was speaking conceptually.  In practice databases maintain b-trees to record numbers in the rid table.  When the database deletes a record, it removes the record's entry from each of the indexes for the table, just as it adds entries into the b-tree when a record is added.  So an index will slow down inserts, deletes, and updates which affect the index, but speed up queries.